# About aruco error import 'cv2.aruco' error on python3.5

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04, opencv, aruco, python

I get an error like the following.

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_sensor.py", line 97, in <module>
    detector = ArucoDetector(sensor.camera, data["detector_layout_path"])
  File "/home/usr/deeptracking/deeptracking/detector/detector_aruco.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.camparam = aruco.CameraParameters()
NameError: name 'aruco' is not defined
```

but, I have installed `cv2.aruco`.
What is the problem?

**environment**

- ubuntu 16.04
- python 3.5
- cuda 9.2

Comment: How did you do the install? Is it possible that the install targeted Python 2.7 instead of 3.5? –

Comment: @DaveW.Smith
Because I am building the environment with python 3, I would like to do it if possible.
But I will try it even in python 2. Thank you!

Comment: @ Dave W. Smith
other program worked using aruco. CameraParameters not found.  Is there not it in cv2.aruco that is in opencv3?

Answer (score 0):

TRY using 
import cv2.aruco as aruco